# How can I turn off the battery meter on my Thinkpad T500?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T500 with Windows 7 Enterprise (n). Even though my laptop is docked (or plugged in), there is a battery meter to the left of the system tray:

[image]

I'd like to turn that off if possible. Has anyone else been able to do that?

Answer (score 5):

Which battery meter? The Power Manager one or the default one? The default one can be turned off in the customization of the notification icons. Right click on Taskbar -> properties -> Notification area: Customize -> At the bottom Turn system .... There you go.
If you talk about the Power manager one. Click with left mouse button on the gauge. Options tab. Show power manager gauge...
Hope you wanted this answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

launch Power Manager and go to Options & uncheck "**Show Power Manager gauge in Task Bar**"

[image]

I own a Thinkpad T430s & this is how it can be done. Easy

Answer (score 0):

Good question -- I'm wondering if there is a specific setting in the Power Manager that would enable one to disable the annoying green brightness meter which pops up everytime the screen brightness auto-resets under battery usage as a way of conserving power.

Comment: Try updating your Power Manager using the "System Update" utility. The new one comes in a stylish gray color, its a pleasure for the eyes. :))